# Prevent chat messages from executing scripts in the browser after being sent from MySQL server?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am making a chat application where people can send messages back and forth. I just realized that when submitting a message, it will execute the script in the browser. If I submit the message `<script>alert("hello");</script>` My browser will execute the script, and the message div will have no message content. When I look at the server, the "content" column has the script inside of it. When I load all of the messages between the user and I, it will run the script... again. The issue im running into is, how do I display the messages in just text, without running the script? I am forming large HTML blocks inside the php sever, then `echo` each one to the `AJAX` requests that appends them in the conversation div. As a simplified version of what I am doing this is basically the text block I `echo` out after getting the values from the database.

```
$chat_message='
<div class="messaging-block">
    <div id="date">'.$date.'</div>
    <div id="username">'.$fname.' '.$lname.'</div>
    <div id="content">'.$content.'</div>
</div>';
echo $chat_message;
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'get-chat-messages.php',
dataType: 'html', //have tried 'text' as well
data: 'convid=' + conversation,
success: function(response) {
  $("#conversation-div").append(response);
                      }        });
```

Comment: [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or possibly [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) could help

Comment: do all websites strip tags? im pretty sure i can type scripts into facebook messenger and have them show up. what would their method be?

Answer (score 0):

Other programs have strip tags func, try googling that or something similar, I am pretty sure that there is function strip tags or something similar for what you are looking for.

Googling XSS prevention is probably also a good idea.

I see you mentioned echo. Php has strip tags 100%